# How to pass LinkedService name to data flow from ADF pipeline?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am working on a migration project where the source data resides in 4 different ADLS Gen 2 account and needs to be migrated to some other data lake.
For this, I have created 4 LinkedService to connect to these source Gen 2 account.

Now I want to pass LinkedService name to DataFlow at run time depending on the data source I want to run data flow for, to connect to respective ADLS Gen2 account.

I am able to pass other parameter from pipeline to dataflow. But passing LinkedService name is not working.

[image]

Comment: I'm afraid to say it's not supported, we can parameter the linked service.

Comment: Hi @Leon Yue, So does that also mean we can't pass parameter from DataFlow to linked service ?

Comment: Yes, it does. We can't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid to say it's not supported.

Data Factory doesn't support pass parameter(pipeline parameter or Data Flow parameter) to linked service. Like you said, We can't pass parameter from Data Flow to linked service.

HTH.